# Unity 19.4.15 Zenject 9.8 CS1513: But Already Closed All Functions/Class

Tags: unity-game-engine, zenject

[edited]

Move [inject] label isn't working //<--Because is [Inject]

Now it has two error:

Assets\player\playercontroller\armory\rifle.cs(10,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'injectAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\player\playercontroller\armory\rifle.cs(10,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'inject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

New code is here.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Zenject;

namespace zenject.injection
{ 
    public class InjectObject
    {
        [inject] //<is [Inject],fu
        GameObject RifleMuzzle;
    }

 
public class rifle : Weapon
{
   
   // Start is called before the first frame update
    private float cooldownTime = 0f;
    private float mag = 5;
    private int magSize = 5;
    
    public void Rifle() 
    {
        
    }
       
    

    public void Cooldown( float time ) 
    {
        cooldownTime -= time;
    }

    public void Fire() 
    {
        
        if ( cooldownTime <= 0f &&　mag>0) 
        {
            RayCast.GetRay();
            RayCast.GetRay(Muzzle.transform.position,Vector3.forward,0f);     

            cooldownTime = 0.1f;
            mag = mag - 1;
            if (mag == 0)
            {
                reload();
            }
        }
    }

    public void reload()
    {
        mag = magSize;
    }

    
}
}
```

---

Before started,I had to thanks Everyone help me to figure out problem

I've already looked [Getting CS1513 } Expected, but all braces are there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868807/getting-cs1513-expected-but-all-braces-are-there)
But it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;





public class rifle : Weapon
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private float cooldownTime = 0f;
    private float mag = 5;
    private int magSize = 5;
    private GameObject Muzzle = GameObject.Find("RifleMuzzle"); //I tried to deleted this,not working T_T
    public void Awake() 
    {  //<-- Assets\player\playercontroller\armory\rifle.cs(13,6): error CS1513: } expected
       [inject]
       Gameobject RifleMuzzle; 
    }  //<-- What complier asked for.
       
    

    public void Cooldown( float time ) 
    {
        cooldownTime -= time;
    }

    public void Fire() 
    {
        
        if ( cooldownTime <= 0f &&　mag>0) 
        {
            RayCast.GetRay();
            RayCast.GetRay(Muzzle.transform.position,Vector3.forward,0f);     

            cooldownTime = 0.1f;
            mag = mag - 1;
            if (mag == 0)
            {
                reload();
            }
        }
    }

    public void reload()
    {
        mag = magSize;
    }
}  //<-- Assets\player\playercontroller\armory\rifle.cs(47,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected 
//If I delete line 13,it'll disappared.
```

Comment: why is [inject] inside a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`[Inject]`](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject/blob/master/AssemblyBuild/Zenject-usage/InjectAttribute.cs)

Is only allowed on

- Constructor
- Method
- Parameter
- Field
- Property

For your **local variable** `RifleMuzzle` inside of `Awake` it is not suitable (actually [no attribute is](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.attributetargets)). Therefore the compiler simply assumes you wanted to close the `Awake` method before introducing a class **field** `RifleMuzzle` with the `[Inject]` attribute.

---

It should probably rather be

```
[Inject]
private GameObject Muzzle; //or RifleMuzzle 

private void Awake() 
{
   // Wouldn't be needed if empty anyway
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it after I back to home

Comment: Assets\player\playercontroller\armory\rifle.cs(10,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'injectAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @黃天貓 oh well yeah ... copy-pasted your typo ^^ it's `Inject` not `inject`